# error on bind_param , number of parameters in prepared statement doesn't match

Tags: php, mysql

I know there are some questions about this, I have tried, but none of those solved my problem. so here is my problem.

I am trying to get a user's data, there are 2 parameters needed, if both of parameters are available, the code run seamlessly, but if `$word` parameter is not available, then I have got this warning + correct result

> **Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Twitter/security/access.php on
>   line 379**
>
> {"users":[{"id":53,"username":"paulpogba","email":"twitter.gadungan@gmail.com","avatar":"","fullname":"paul
>   pogba"},{"id":56,"username":"waynerooney","email":"islam.idn@gmail.com","avatar":"","fullname":"wayne
>   rooney"}]}

the JSON result is good as i expect. but i want to omit the warning message. the problem is on the `$statement-> bind_param('ss',$words,$words);` i believe there are only 2 `?` in the SQL syntax.

I don't know why it is said Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement, I can't see what went wrong in here :(

```
 function searchUsers ($currentUser,$words) {


        $query = "SELECT id,username,email,avatar,fullname FROM users WHERE NOT username= '$currentUser'";

        if (!empty($words))  {
            $query .= "AND (username LIKE ? OR fullname LIKE ?)";
        }


        $statement = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        if (!$statement) {
            throw new Exception($statement->error);
        }



        if (!empty($words)) {
            $words = "%".$words."%";
        }



        $statement-> bind_param('ss',$words,$words);
        $statement ->execute();

        // result we got in execution
        $result = $statement->get_result();

        // each time append to $returnArray new row one by one when it is found
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $returnArray[] = $row;
        }

        return $returnArray;


    }
```

Comment: If `$words` is __empty__ there's no need to `bind_param`. Understood?

Comment: so actually this is not a problem right? since those bind_param never be executed when $words is not available. am i right? sorry, i am a beginner in programming :D

Comment: In your code `bind_param` is __always executed__.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
$statement-> bind_param('ss',$words,$words);
```

you need

```
if ($words) {
    $statement-> bind_param('ss',$words,$words);
}
```

Explanation: You need to add those parameters if and only if `$words` is truey.

Comment: Thanks Lajos, but my $words is actually a string sent from mobile app, but it seems like a boolean value from your code. so PHP automatically gives  true value if a avariable is not null?  like != nil in other programming language? sorry if i ask this question, i am new in PHP. Thanks :)

Comment: @AgungLaksana there are truey and falsey values in PHP. For instance 'abc' is truey, (!!'abc') === true. '' is falsey. However, a truey of falsey value is not necessarily true or false, but logically will be evaluated to the logical value it is closer to.